# NoReserveMatch error when passing multiple parameters to template

Tags: django

I'm getting a NoReverseMatch error:

```
Reverse for 'state' with arguments '('', '')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I have 2 ids being passed to the template and that seems to be the problem.

views.py

```
def state(request, country_id, state_id):
    countrystate = State.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("template.html", {'countrystate': countrystate})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^my_index/(?P<country_id>\d+)/$', 'my_App.views.main', name='main'),
url(r'^my_index/(?P<country_id>\d+)/value/$', 'my_App.views.value', name='value'),
url(r'^my_index/(?P<country_id>\d+)/option/$', 'my_App.views.option', name='option'),
url(r'^my_index/(?P<country_id>\d+)/state/$', 'my_App.views.country', name='country'),
url(r'^my_index/(?P<country_id>\d+)/state/(?P<state_id>\d+)/$', 'my_App.views.state', name='state'),
```

template.html

```
{% load url from future %}
<form class="option_form" action="{% url "state" country.id state.id %}" method="post">
```

any ideas?

Edit:
What I have is a list of countries and states. So in other templates, I can pick a country from a list and then I can pick a state from the country. That's where I am right now. After picking my state, I am trying to render the template above but am getting a noreversematch. The state.id and country.ids are in the url. I can do this fine with country.id only but can't do it both with country and state.id.

Comment: Try {% url "my_App.views.state" country.id state.id %} and see if you get the same error.

Comment: that didn't seem to work. I can build the view if there is only 1 parameter (ie, country.id and no state.id) but putting 2 parameters in seem to break it.

Comment: Post your entire urls.py file.

Comment: done. posted the patterns above.

Comment: Where is country and state being passed in to the template? They are being evaluated I believe as '' and ''.  They need to be passed in via a context processor or by the view.

Comment: How would I pass those 2 via the view? I thought country.id and state.id are being passed via the url.

Comment: Typically for which ever view displays the page it would be {'country': country, 'state' : state} in the views render_to_response. Of course country and state have to be defined in the view also. For example country = Country.objects.all()[0] similar for state.

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work. I'll post more of an explanation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a view similar to the following:

```
def state(request, country_id, state_id):
    my_state = State.objects.all()[0]
    my_country = Country.objects.all()[0]
    return render_to_response("template.html", {'state': my_state, 'country': my country })
```

The function above is nonsensical, but should not produce an error.

If you are defining country and state via some select tool on the web page, then

it will never work, as this is being evaluated BEFORE it goes to the users browser.

I'm not saying you can not get the form to work, just that this approach is wrong.

Comment: I am defining country and state from a previous web page that will lead me to a url such as http://myurl.com/1/2/ with country =1 and state = 2. Then I want this template to take and render the url with values from country =1 and state =2. Your solution fixes the error for me but does not change the output of the state (ie, if I change the states in my url, the update is not shown in my template).

Comment: Solved it using a get_object_or_404 function. But couldn't have done it w/o this answer. Thanks mtnpaul!

Answer (score 0):

When you use only 1 parameter, is my_App.views.country being used?  Try reversing the order of the last 2 urls...

```
url(r'^my_index/(?P<country_id>\d+)/state/(?P<state_id>\d+)/$', 'my_App.views.state', name='state'),
url(r'^my_index/(?P<country_id>\d+)/state/$', 'my_App.views.country', name='country'),
```

Comment: I reversed the order and even commented out the country url. Still gives me the same error.